# $f (x) = 1$ if the digit $9$ appears in the decimal representation of $x$ and $f (x) = 0$ otherwise — show that $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, epsilon-delta

> The function $f : [0, 1] \to \Bbb R$, where $f (x) = 1$ if the digit $9$ appears in the decimal representation of $x$ and $f (x) = 0$ otherwise. We use a decimal representation that does not end in repeating $9$s. 
>  Show that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $f (x) = 1$. 
>  (Use only $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ definition of continues. You are not allowed use limit).

---

I intuitively know that if $x$ is a decimal which appears $9$ then we can find another decimal in any neighbourhood with the same property. if not then again we can find another decimal in any neighbourhood which appears $9$. But how write it formally I couldn't. After several days I gave up. Actually I understand the basic idea. But I couldn't write formally anything. Please help me.

Comment: so, what is the basic idea?

Comment: You have two directions of the "if and only if" to prove, and the definition of continuity to use. That alone gives you most of the structure of your proof. Which parts are you having trouble filling in? Or are you having trouble with the basic proof structure?

Comment: It should be pretty easy for you to show that if $f(x) = 0$, then $f$ is *not* continuous at $x$.  Can you use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity to do that?

Comment: I know that if $x$ is a decimal which appears $9$ then we can find another decimal in any neighbourhood with the same property. if not then again we can find another decimal in any neighbourhood which appears 9. but how write it formally I couldn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of numbers with a $9$ in the decimal representation is dense in $[0, 1]$ (just replace the $n$-th digit by $9,$ for some high $n.$) This shows that the function is *not* continuous if it is $0.$ On the other hand, the set of numbers which **do not** have a nine is not dense (a number which has a nine in the $k$-th position will have it if perturbed by something smaller than $10^{-k-2}.$)

Comment: @WillJagy Realy? What is the number close to $0.9$ with no nines?

Comment: hmmmmmm. let's see, if all digits are fro $0$ to $8,$  no larger than all $8$  which is $8/9,$  so anything between that and $9/10$ has a 9. Good thinking!

Answer (score 3):

A more elementary approach,

First of all let $f(x)= 0$ then i.e. $x = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_i}{10^i}$ where $x_{i}\neq 9$, $\forall \ i$. Then for every $\epsilon >0 $, there exists large enough $i_0$ such that, $y := \sum_{i=1}^{i_0 - 1} \frac{x_i}{10^i} + \frac{9}{10^{i_0}} + \sum_{i=i_0}^{\infty} \frac{x_i}{10^i}$, is $\epsilon$-close to $x$, but $f(y)=1$. So indeed $f$ is not continuous at $x$ where $f(x)=0$.

Now let $f(x)=1$. Then $9$ appears in its decimal representation and consider $i_1\geq 1$ such that $9$ appears for the first time in its decimal expansion i.e.  $x = \sum_{i=1}^{i_1 - 1} \frac{x_i}{10^i} + \frac{9}{10^{i_1}} + \sum_{i=i_1}^{\infty} \frac{x_i}{10^i}$, where $x_i\neq 9$ for all $1\leq i < i_1$. Then for $\epsilon_1 < \frac{9}{10^{i_1 +1}}$ we have that every $y$ that is $\epsilon_1$-near $x$ has $9$ in its decimal expansion and more precisely $y_i = x_i$ for (at least) all $1\leq i \leq i_1$